# rails server vs preview method in Ruby On Rails - mad_chatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi Everyone 
 I was integrating [mad_chatter](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mad_chatter/0.3.4) in my rails application .
Where i saw `preview method` for starting application as `mad_chatter preview` 
.

- I googled it but could not find this method .  Can any one tell what
  is this `preview method`.Any reference to documentation will be
  appreciated
- what is difference between `rails server` and
  `preview`

Note: I can not tell anything more about it as I didn't found it else where except the mentioned link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preview` is [part of the mad_chatter gem](https://github.com/andrewhavens/mad_chatter/blob/master/bin/mad_chatter#L29).
To view the contents of a gem locally, user `gem open mad_chatter`, or, more simply, just take a look at the github page for the gem.

Comment: my bad :( - i missed that